# Will Android in USB accessory mode function immediately as USB host mode after physically disconnecting a connected USB device?

Tags: android, usb, host, accessory

We want the USB device connected to Android to act as a USB accessory when it is a USB host and to act as a USB host when it is a USB device.

At this time, when the USB device connected to Android switches from USB host to USB device, the connection is assumed to be broken once.

Under this condition, is it possible for Android to operate as a USB host?